# G:textfield remote function advice needed

Tags: ajax, grails, groovy

i need advice on groovy. My remote function's not working. here is my codes. please advice.

```
<g:textField name="name"
                  onchange="${remoteFunction(action:'validateName',update:'errorName', params:'\'name=\' + this.value' )}"/>
```

Comment: and! what u wanna do?!?!

Comment: I want to validate the textfield when people edit using ajax

Answer (score 0):

The [remote constraints](http://www.grails.org/plugin/remote-constraints) plugin does most of the work for you.

And, if you want to use only the ajax function you have to use the "remoteConstraints" tag:

```
 <g:remoteConstraints 
   beanName="Test" 
   fieldName="name" 
   template="/shared/error" 
   var="errorBean"
   updateElement="errorsDiv"/>
```